# Issues deploying mvc application that has users and needs an update on the database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to seed an admin user to my database so that when I deploy, I have one user that can log in....

This is the seed method that I am trying to run, but it gives me  "no suitable method found to override". My application user is the stock application user that visual studio gives you in the template.

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            var passwordHash = new PasswordHasher();
            string password = passwordHash.HashPassword("Password@123");
            context.Users.AddOrUpdate(u => u.UserName,
                new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = "Steve@Steve.com",
                    PasswordHash = password,
                    PhoneNumber = "08869879"

                });
        }
```

Comment: Are you  inheriting from `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TContext>`? To override method `Seed` need to use corectly base class. In this case it should be `DropCreareDatabaseAlways<TContext>`

Comment: I figured it out. I wasn't passing the parent class the ApplicationDbContext. Is there a way that I can seed from 2 difference contexts?

Comment: Maybe creating BaseContext will be good idea, where you override `Seed`

Comment: No. Only one context per project can be migrated, so your seed will always be specific to whichever context that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class where you override `Seed` method need inheriting from `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TContext>`. 
Error :

> no suitable method found to override

Mean only that base class not contains `Seed` method. You can override it like:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(YourContext context)
    {
        //add data
    }
}
```